# How to load a customer profile from address module

Tags: 8, users, commerce

I'm using Drupal 8 with the module Commerce  and I have an issue with the customer address.

I'm developing an export custom module in D8, and I'm stuck trying to load the profile (to access billing and shipping address) of a customer.

I'm not able to access this data from the custom module. And there is no documentation about the address pluggin ( https://www.drupal.org/project/address )

I have tried to load the order and the user data but there is no relevant field that helps  me to achieve this.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can try get profile by order and can try the code below:

```
$order_id =1;
$entityManager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$order = $entityManager->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($order_id);
```

get address by field `billing_profile`

```
$address = $order->billing_profile->entity->address->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the customer profile is a content entity you can access customer profile information by using the entityTypeManager() function.

```
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$profile = $entity_manager->getStorage('profile')->load($profile_id);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't know the profile id and you're looking for the user profiles, try using $entity_manager->getStorage('profile')->loadByUser($account, 'customer', TRUE); and there's also loadMultipleByUser() and loadDefaultByUser().

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the order, this may help you:

```
if ($this->order->hasField('shipments') && !$this->order->get('shipments')->isEmpty() ) {
  $order_shipments = $this->order->get('shipments')->referencedEntities();
  $order_shipment = reset($order_shipments);
  $shipment_profile = $order_shipment->getShippingProfile();
  
  // Prepare shipment information.
  $addressValues = $shipment_profile->address->getValue();
  $shipment['locality'] = $addressValues[0]['locality'];
  $shipment['administrative_area'] = $addressValues[0]['administrative_area'];
  $shipment['postal_code'] = $addressValues[0]['postal_code'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

customer profile is a entity type and can be loaded by profile_id by using the entityTypeManager()

```
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$profile = $entity_manager->getStorage('profile')->load($profile_id);
```

if you don't know the **profile_id** in the first place It can be also be loaded by properties using loadByProperties() method

```
$values = [
            'field_phone' => "123456789",
            "address" => [
                "country_code" => "BD",
            ]
        ];
$profile = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('profile')->loadByProperties($values);
```

Following fields are available for filtering for the profile

```
      "revision_id"
      "type"
      "uuid"
      "status"
      "uid"
      "is_default"
      "data"
      "created"
      "changed"
      "revision_created"
      "revision_user"
      "revision_log_message"
      "revision_default"
      "isDefaultRevision"
      "address"
      "field_phone"
```

last field is **field_phone** is created from cms which located in Profile config page **(/admin/config/people/profile-types/manage/customer/fields)**.